# AngularJS : why checkbox is display?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to make a simple demo of a multiple select option. I also have a limit in my demo. In other words, a user can only select two items.

I am able to do that but when a user selects a third one, a checkbox is selected for the second. Alert is display when I press the ok button then it become unchecked. I would like only the alert to be displayed when a user select third item.
here is my code
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqdmNv

The click button shows a pop up screen. Select "A" and "B" then "C". It shows "c" checked and alert is display when the user presses ok then c becomes unchecked. I only need the alert not "c" to become checked  for second.

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('MyController', function($scope, $ionicPopover) {
  $scope.MAX=2;
  $scope.countMax = 0;
  $scope.data =[
    {"name":"A", value:false},
    {"name":"B", value:false},
    {"name":"C", value:false},
    {"name":"D", value:false},
    {"name":"E", value:false}
  ]
  $ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('my-popover.html', {
    scope: $scope
  }).then(function(popover) {
    $scope.popover = popover;
  });


  $scope.openPopover = function($event) {
    $scope.popover.show($event);
  };

   $scope.closePopover = function() {
    $scope.popover.hide();
  };
  $scope.maxCheck = function($index){
    $scope.countMax = 0;
    for(i=0;i<$scope.data.length;i++){
      if($scope.data[i].value == true)
        $scope.countMax++;
    }
    console.log("CALC",$scope.countMax,$scope.MAX)
    if($scope.countMax > $scope.MAX){
      $scope.data[$index].value = false;
      alert("limit reached");
    }



  }
}
)
```

Comment: it's mandatory the use of an alert? may be you can use something like http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/, because an alert pause your code and produce this.

Comment: any other way to do that

Comment: could you use plunker or codepen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your `alert` in a `setTimeout`. [codepen](http://codepen.io/alex-wilmer/pen/MwJRvq?editors=001)

```
  setTimeout(function () {
    alert("limit reached");
  });
```

By doing this, the alert doesn't block execution so your checkbox logic can finish before the alert pops up. Essentially the alert is being chucked onto the end of the [browser event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

Answer (score 0):

Hi shruti You can make use of ng-disabled , so that once the count==2 disabled the other radio buttons.

```
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.value" ng-click="maxCheck($index)" ng-disabled="dis">

 $scope.countMax = 0;
  $scope.dis=false;
  $scope.maxCheck = function($index){
   var z=0;
    for(i=0;i<$scope.data.length;i++){

       if($scope.data[i].value == true)
         {
            if($scope.countMax >= $scope.MAX)
             {
                alert("limit reached");
               //$scope.data[$index].value = false;
                $scope.dis=true;
             }
         else
          $scope.countMax++;
         }



    }
```

Make countMax as global.